# Given a list of N numbers, how to find the number of indices the maximum number will have to move in order to reach end of list

Tags: python

How to go to the end of the list after finding the max number?

Input : 
1

5

3 5 2 4 2

Output :

3

Comment: Just find the index of the `max` in your list then subtract it from `len` of your list: `len(l)-l.index(max(l))-1`, with the fact list are with zero based indexing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `list.index()` and `max(list)` to get the index of the maximum value, then subtract it from the length of the list to get the distance it will have to move:

```
>>> a = [3, 5, 2, 4, 2]
>>> len(a) - (a.index(max(a)) + 1)
3
```